# Create n agents and calculate average number

Tags: javaagents, agents-jade, multi-agent

I want to create system of n agents. All agents are generate random Integer value. My goal is calculating average of these n numbers.
My simple idea of algorithm:

- Every Agent sends message with its number to other agents
- Every Agent calculates average number

Problems:

- I just can't understand how I can create a variable number of agents
- How I can take output result

Maybe somebody know how I can do this?

Comment: FYI, you should generally only ask one question per post.

Comment: Simple suggestion : If the problem can be solved by using a `algorithmic manner`, then there is no use of following `multi agent` approach.

Comment: I agree with @Keshan. Unless this is a learning project, there's no need for agents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples online tend to focus on using the `Boot` class:

```
java -cp jade.jar jade.Boot -agents agentName:org.agents.MyAgentClass
```

You could spawn more agents simply by adding more to the `-agents` option command-line args (separated by semi-colons):

```
java -cp jade.jar jade.Boot -agents \
    agent1:org.agents.MyAgentClass;agent2:org.agents.MyAgentClass
```

If you need a *variable* number of agents, you could move this to a bash script that appends more agents depending on a parameter.

If you really want to go crazy, you can create your own container and add agents to it from your own code and bypass the `Boot` class. Since your use case is so simple, I don't know that this would be a good way to go yet.